# Why does Set-AzStorageBlobContent task status always stay Active and never completes?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am retrieving files from a directory and uploading them to an Azure Blob Storage account with the following Powershell command:

```
Get-ChildItem $ArtifactStagingDirectory -Recurse -File | Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $StorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Force
```

I am running this in the Windows PowerShell ISE.  There are two files to upload and the ISE shows both being uploaded, but the overall task status stays as:
Total: 2. Successful: 0. Failed: 0. Active 2.

Both of the files are actually uploaded to the Azure storage.  However, this powershell command never completes and never moves to the next command.

I am looking for reasons why this might be or for ways to help troubleshoot the issue.  I am new to using the Windows Powershell ISE.

```
Get-ChildItem $ArtifactStagingDirectory -Recurse -File | Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $StorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Force
```

I have tried including the -ClientTimeoutPerRequest property, which did not change the results.

Comment: Does it work well in powershell prompt?

Comment: It appears to work correctly within Windows Powershell.

Comment: To further clarify: If I run it within Windows Powershell as a command, it completes.  If I run my script in Windows Powershell, it does not complete.  I'm going to strip my script down to just this and see if it will work.

Comment: So, calling this within a script works.  But, my script displays a WPF window and is calling this from a button click event.  I stripped my button click event to be exactly what is in my working script and I have the issue.  It never fully completes.

Comment: Could you please show us a sample code that how do you call powershell script in your WPF window?

Comment: Ivan, it's really the other way around - the powershell script loads and display a WPF window.  That said, this statement works if I create a runspace and call it in that thread.  This is ultimately what I wanted to do anyway, so I'm calling this solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I wrap the statement in a runspace, it completes as it should.  As this is what I ultimately wanted to do anyway, I'm considering this question answered.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but could you provide an example? I'm a beginner with PS and I don't know what runspaces are or how to use them